# How to calculate percentage breakdown of a relationship property in Cypher and NeoDash

Tags: neo4j, cypher, percentage

I am looking to create a bar chart in NeoDash using Cypher which gives the percentage of each response (r.Response), (Categories are - Accepted, Declined etc.), a property of the [r:RE_INVITED_TO] relationship, broken down by Gender (p.Gender). Here is my current code -

```
MATCH (p:REPerson)-[r:RE_INVITED_TO]-(:REEvent)
WITH SUM(toInteger(r.Response)) As total
MATCH (p:REPerson)-[r:RE_INVITED_TO]-(:REEvent)
RETURN p.Gender, count(p),  100.0 * SUM(r.Response) / total
```

Currently it gives me the error message

```
sum() can only handle numerical values, duration, and null. Got String("Accepted")
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code, instead of trying to sum responses, you simply count them. Sum is used to sum numerical values, while count is used to count any graph patterns. Also, remember that Cypher has implicit aggregation grouping.

```
MATCH (:REPerson)-[r:RE_INVITED_TO]-(:REEvent)
WITH count(r) As total
MATCH (p:REPerson)-[r:RE_INVITED_TO]-(:REEvent)
RETURN p.Gender, r.Response, 100.0 * count(r) / total AS ratio
```